# React unit testing, cannot read 'push' of undefined react router

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component that uses react router like so:

```
_viewCompany(companyId) {
    this.context.router.push(`/admin/companies/${companyId}`);
}
```

It works great in the component, but while writing tests for the component I ran into an error. Here is the test causing the issue (I am using enzyme, jest, sinon):

```
    it('should call _viewCompany', () => {
        jest.spyOn(CompaniesList.prototype, '_viewCompany');
        wrapper = mount(<CompaniesList {...props}/>);
        const viewButton = wrapper.find('.btn-info').at(0);
        viewButton.simulate('click');
        expect(CompaniesList.prototype._viewCompany).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

This test returns an error saying the following:

`Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

Is there something I can do to mock it or create an empty function for the tests?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to pass context object while mounting the component.

```
function Router () {
   this.router = [];

   this.push = function(a) {
     this.router.push(a);
   };

   this.get = function(index){
      return this.router[index];
   }
    this.length = function(){
     return this.router.length;
   }
}

function History () {
   this.history = [];

   this.push = function(a) {
    this.history.push(a);
    };

    this.get = function(index){
     return this.history[index];
    }
   this.length = function(){
      return this.history.length;
   }
}

it('should call _viewCompany', () => {
    jest.spyOn(CompaniesList.prototype, '_viewCompany');
    wrapper = mount(<CompaniesList {...props}/>,{context:{router: new 
                Router(), history: new History()}});
    const viewButton = wrapper.find('.btn-info').at(0);
    viewButton.simulate('click');
    expect(CompaniesList.prototype._viewCompany).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(wrapper.context().router.length()).toEqual('1');
});
```

You can even test the context object as well. Like I did above.